# Get text returned of javascript action in applescript

Tags: javascript, applescript

So I want to have a script that presses a button for me and if the button doesn't exist, it keeps clicking until the button exists. The approach I tried was to get the `text returned` of my JavaScript action, because if the button I try to press doesn't exist, it will normally write `missing value` to the result tab in the Script editor. The approach didn't work since the code down below wouldn't even compile.

```
repeat until text returned of theAction is not equal to "missing value"
    tell application "Google Chrome"
        tell active tab of front window to set theAction to execute javascript "document.getElementById('getQualities').click();"
    end tell
end repeat
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I want to have a script that presses a button for me and if the button doesn't exist, it keeps clicking until the button exists.

Here is a method that I would use and should work. I say *should* as I cannot test based on the *element* being `getQualities`. However, I did test the *code* using a known *element* on the page of this question and it worked.

---

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
set theElementExists to false

repeat until theElementExists
    tell application "Google Chrome" to ¬
        set theElementExists to ¬
            execute front window's active tab javascript ¬
                "document.body.contains(document.getElementById('getQualities'));"
    delay 1
end repeat

if theElementExists then
    tell application "Google Chrome" to ¬
        execute front window's active tab javascript ¬
            "document.getElementById('getQualities'}.click();"
end if
```

---

**Notes:**

I'm not a big fan of using endless loops constructs, but when I do, I typically add additional *code* to terminate the *script* after a reasonable time out period. (Which of course makes them not an endless loop.)

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
set theElementExists to false

set i to 0
repeat until theElementExists
    tell application "Google Chrome" to ¬
        set theElementExists to ¬
            execute front window's active tab javascript ¬
                "document.body.contains(document.getElementById('getQualities'));"
    delay 1
    set i to i + 1
    if i ≥ 10 then return
end repeat
```

As coded this would run for up to 10 seconds.

The `document.body.contains()` method returns a *Boolean value*.

Note that the second `if` *statement* `if theElementExists then` is not really necessary per se, and I've included it mainly for coding clarity.

In case you are wondering how I tested it, I used the following within my *code*, which targets the **Ask Question** *button* on this page:

```
"document.body.contains(document.getElementsByClassName('ws-nowrap s-btn s-btn__primary')[0]);"
```

And:

```
"document.getElementsByClassName('ws-nowrap s-btn s-btn__primary')[0].click();"
```

While manually setting focus to a different page first, then manually setting focus back to this page and it clicked the **Ask Question** *button*.